# Clone element from div to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, insertafter

I need to build simple tabs menu. The problem is that I must generate somethink like that ...

```
 <ul id="menu">
  <li class="First">First</li>
  <li class="Second">Second</li>
  <li class="Third">Third</li>
</ul>
```

...from somethink like that

```
<div class="someclass">
     <li class="First">First</li>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
<div class="someclass">
     <li class="Second">Second</li>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
<div class="someclass">
     <li class="Third">Third</li>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
```

I tried to solve this broblem with my pure knowledge in js...

```
<div id="PutAfter">  
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="m">First</li>
  <li id="m">Second</li>
  <li id="m">Third</li>
</ul>
   <div style="display:none"> 
<div class="someclass">
     <li id="m">4</li>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
<div class="someclass">
     <li id="m">5</li>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="someclass">
     <li id="m">6</li>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and simple script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#4').clone().insertAfter($('#m3'));
     $('#5').clone().insertAfter($('#4'));
     $('#6').clone().insertAfter($('#5'));
});
```

As you can see there is big problem - duplicates in ids :( I cant generate ids for `<li>` elements i script because menu load in header.phtml file and `<div>` content in footer.phtml so I dont know exactly how much ids I need (thats why I cant get menu items using php - forget about standart "get from db" its Zend...). Maybe I need to generate or just get some "array"?

I would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: Duplicated ID's seem to be the least of your problems, a list element can't be a child of a DIV, so the markup probably isn't even what you think it is, as the browser in most cases will try to fix stuff like that.

Comment: Talking about the duplicated id's... If the problem is that the `li`'s count may vary, why not set a class instead of an id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all `li` inside `.someclass` elements, clone them and add to newly created `ul`, adding then it to `body`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydbcb43z/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ul = $('<ul>', { id: "menu" });
    ul.append($('.someclass li').clone());
    $("body").append(ul);
});
```